# there does not exist a perfect square of the form $7\ell+3$

Tags: number-theory

I have been trying to prove that there does not exist a perfect square of the form $7\ell+3$.  I've tried using $n$ as even or odd, and I'm getting stuck.  Can someone put me on the path?  Is this an equivalence class problem?

Comment: Hint: whether $n$ is even or odd tells you absolutely nothing about the remainder of $n^2$ when divided by $7$.  But if $n$ is divisible by $7$ then you do know something about $n^2$.  What if $n$ is not divisible by $7$?  Can you see that there are several subcases to consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n^2\equiv3\mod7$, then $(n\bmod7)^2\equiv3\mod7$ as well.

Indeed, $n\bmod7=n-7q$, so that $(n\bmod7)^2=(n-7q)^2=n^2+7(-2n+7q^2)$.

So yes, it is an equivalence class problem.

Answer (score 1):

For any integer $a,$

$$a\equiv0,\pm1,\pm2,\pm3\pmod7\implies a^2\equiv0,1,4,9\equiv2$$

$$\implies a^2\not\equiv3(=7-4),5(=7-2),6(=7-1)\pmod7$$

Answer (score 1):

First, notice that $[n\text{ is a perfect square}]\implies[n\equiv\color\green{0,1,2,4}\pmod7]$:

- $k\equiv0\pmod7 \implies k^2\equiv0^2\equiv0\pmod7$
- $k\equiv1\pmod7 \implies k^2\equiv1^2\equiv1\pmod7$
- $k\equiv2\pmod7 \implies k^2\equiv2^2\equiv4\pmod7$
- $k\equiv3\pmod7 \implies k^2\equiv3^2\equiv2\pmod7$
- $k\equiv4\pmod7 \implies k^2\equiv4^2\equiv2\pmod7$
- $k\equiv5\pmod7 \implies k^2\equiv5^2\equiv4\pmod7$
- $k\equiv6\pmod7 \implies k^2\equiv6^2\equiv1\pmod7$

Second, observe that $[n\text{ is an integer}]\implies[7n+3\equiv\color\red3\pmod7]$.

Answer (score 1):

$7\ell+3=n^2$ would imply $n^2\equiv 3\pmod 7$, but $3$ is a quadratic nonresidue modulo $7$.

Answer (score 0):

Unusual method: without finding all the quadratic residues mod $7$:

$a^2\equiv 3\pmod{7}\implies a^6\equiv 3^3\equiv 27\equiv 6\pmod{7},$

which contradicts [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).